# Angular 7 Application Performance Slowdown

Tags: angular, rxjs6, google-visualization

I have created one monthly dashboard in my Angular 7 application, it show 8 charts(built by google charts) for every month and first chart details as a table to the bottom of charts div.

When I change month 8 different APIs will call and load data for 8 charts.

Here the issue is my application was getting slow down for the time been. Even though I followed API unsubscribe methodology in a correct way, page was falling in slow performance issues.

Only this dashboard page was facing this issue remaining pages are working fine.

Here is the sample code

```
this.widgetsList.forEach((eachWidget, i) => {
this.subsWidg.add(this.dashboardsService.getCountOfInProcessApprovals(this.monthId, this.processType, eachWidget.id).subscribe((res: any[]) => { }))
})

public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subsWidg.unsubscribe();
}
```

**Another Observation**: I have removed all my code in component and added charts with static data(There was no API calls) but still page response is same no change. I guess something is dominating google charts in my application.

Comment: You should have to follow some tips to fast your performance of your app.
Avoid function calline in veiw, Preserve Whitespaces, Avoid Getters in View etc,.... for more detail You can refer this link it will helps a lot..    ** https://angular-guru.com/blog/angular-performance-tips **

Comment: Yes, but here I guess problem is google charts are not fitting in my application because I have removed all the code in my component and added charts with static data no API calls here but problem is still there. And one more thing I did this in new application there was no problem.

Comment: You can remove unnecessary imports, You can use async await while performing API Calls. I hope these helps.

Comment: can you show a stackblitz to see how you are implementing these charts

Comment: @PierreDuc Here is sample code for how I imported charts  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-chart-ecmak6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy.component.ts

Comment: @RamaKrishna I can only imagine you need to add a `trackBy` function to your `*ngFor="let eachChart of charts;"`

Comment: I already added that trackBy in my application

Comment: it appears you are creating a new chart before every time it is drawn (`chart = new google.visualization.LineChart`) -- instead, use the [`ChartWrapper` class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapper-class). save a reference to the chart, before you draw, check to see if the chart already exists, if it does, change the data and / or chart type and re-draw, rather than re-create...